# I need to write a error popup inside div without snackbars with TS

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, typescript, loops

I need to write a popup error handler with html, angular and Typescript. Im trying to think of the best way to do it using ngFor loop for it. Whats the best way to approach it? Im a bit new to all this lol

Comment: Are you using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)?

Comment: yes i am! im needing it inside of a sidebar type of page

Answer (score 0):

Many-many ways to achieve this. Here is a small example.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let notification of notifications">
  <div @fadeIn @fadeOut class="notification-container">
    <div>{{ notification }}</div>
    <button mat-button (click)="remove(notification)" class="red-button">
      X
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<br />
<br />
<button (click)="add()">Add notification</button>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-fade-in-jcx9bu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Though I don't understand why you would want to invent a wheel if you're already using material components. I would advise using material snackbar.

Comment: thank you so much! if you have any tips you can throw me id love to add you on discord or slack or something! Any help helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular material. You should try this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-Component ',
  templateUrl: 'someComponent.html',
})
export class someComponent {
  constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  errorDialog() {
    this._snackBar.open('Error..., 'x');
  }
}
```

Using snack bar from Angular material, you can do it as simple as calling this function to show a error message.

Comment: OP specifically asked without SnackBar, though I agree that using SnackBar would be quite efficient since OP is already using material components.